# Image color correction in android java

Tags: android, image, colors

I am writing a program that allows user to compare the 2 photos, 1 as sample color and the other to be edited. I will gather pixel info from the first then apply the following method to edit the latter.

Resulting photo : http://www.flickr.com/photos/92325795@N02/8392038944/in/photostream

My photo is being updated and despite of the quality/noise/color but there are the weird colors here and there. Anyone have any idea what i should do to remove it? Or even better improve on the method i am using? Heres the code:

The input is the bitmap to edit, inColor is the color of the nose in the photo to be edited, reqcolor is the color of my nose in the sample/optimum photo.

```
public Bitmap shiftRGB(Bitmap input, int inColor, int reqColor){

    int deltaR = Color.red(reqColor) - Color.red(inColor);
    int deltaG = Color.green(reqColor) - Color.green(inColor);
    int deltaB = Color.blue(reqColor) - Color.blue(inColor);

    //--how many pixels ? --
    int w = input.getWidth();
    int h = input.getHeight();


    //-- change em all! --
    for (int i = 0 ; i < w; i++){
        for (int  j = 0 ; j < h ; j++ ){
            int pixColor = input.getPixel(i,j);

            //-- colors now ? --
            int inR = Color.red(pixColor);
            int inG = Color.green(pixColor);
            int inB = Color.blue(pixColor);

            if(inR > 255){ inR = 255;}
            if(inG > 255){ inG = 255;}
            if(inB > 255){ inB = 255;}
            if(inR < 0){ inR = 0;}
            if(inG < 0){ inG = 0;}
            if(inB < 0){ inB = 0;}

            //-- colors then --
            input.setPixel(i,j,Color.argb(255,inR + deltaR,inG + deltaG,inB           + deltaB));
        }
    }

    return input;
```

}
Thank you so much for help me! I cant express my gratitude further than saying another thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The function seems to be working as expected.

However, one thing that I do notice is that you are putting your "if" cases to verify boundaries BEFORE you actually set the final output of the new pixel.

```
        if(inR > 255){ inR = 255;}
        if(inG > 255){ inG = 255;}
        if(inB > 255){ inB = 255;}
        if(inR < 0){ inR = 0;}
        if(inG < 0){ inG = 0;}
        if(inB < 0){ inB = 0;}
        input.setPixel(i,j,Color.argb(255,inR + deltaR,inG + deltaG,inB + deltaB));
```

I believe this is what you are actually trying to do.

```
        inR += deltaR
        inG += deltaG
        inB += deltaB
        if(inR > 255){ inR = 255;}
        if(inG > 255){ inG = 255;}
        if(inB > 255){ inB = 255;}
        if(inR < 0){ inR = 0;}
        if(inG < 0){ inG = 0;}
        if(inB < 0){ inB = 0;}
        input.setPixel(i,j,Color.argb(255,inR,inG,inB));
```

Comment: OMG! i totally didn't notice it haha. Ok thanks WLin! The problem is now fixed :)